# Rewrite labels using methods

Tags: java, swing, methods, jlabel

So to be more specific I want to be able to do "changeLabel(lableHere, textHere);"
but I don't know how to specify the label.
to simplify my request I want to go from

```
public static void method1(String TextToSet){
    if(variable.isVisible()==false){
        variable.setVisible(true);
        variable.setText(TextToSet);
    }else if(variable.isVisible()==true){
        variable.setVisible(false);
    }
}
public static void method2(String TextToSet){
    if(variable2.isVisible()==false){
        variable2.setVisible(true);
        variable2.setText(TextToSet);
    }else if(variable2.isVisible()==true){
        variable2.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

or what I'm using currently:

```
    public static void method(String VariableIWantToChange, String TextToSet){
    if(VariableIWantToChange.equalsIgnoreCase("Variable1"){
        if(Variable1.isVisible()==false){
            Variable1.setVisible(true);
            Variable1.setText(TextToSet);
        }
        else if(Variable1.isVisible()==true){
            Variable1.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    if(VariableIWantToChange.equalIgnoreCase("Variable2"){
        if(Variable2.isVisible()==false){
            Variable2.setVisible(true);
            Variable2.setText(TextToSet);
        }
        else if(Variable2.isVisible()==true){
            Variable2.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

(that method becomes really long after just a few variables)

and instead, have one method that is something like this

```
public static void method( Labeltochange ,String TextToSet){
    if(Labeltochange.isVisible()==false){
        Labeltochange.setVisible(true);
        Labeltochange.setText(TextToSet);
    }
}
```

that allows you to change label by doing `method(LabelToChange, TextToSet);`

Comment: What's the problem with just using `JLabel` as a parameter and calling it like `method(variable, "someText")`?

Comment: For the record: 
A) beyond my answer, even the "mapping" approach is most likely bad practice. But in order to really help you, we would have to understand the problem you actually intend to solve (go google "XY problem"). But that would probably make your question "too broad". B) as some newbies often forget about that: please do not forget about accepting an answer at some point.

Comment: wait if I do `method(JComponent Label, String Text);` can I then use the Label parameter to set what label to set the text on?

edit - failed the coding format :P

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real requirement here: you want to map a name (String) name to some UI element (maybe a JLabel, maybe a JButton, who cares).

The answer: use a n appropriate data structure, like a `Map<String, JComponent>`.

Simply **fill** that map at some point in time:

```
Map<String, JComponent> componentsByName = new HashMap<>(); ...
componentsByName.put("label1", labelA);
```

So, later on, you simply do a `componentsByName.get()` to retrieve ... a component by its "name". To then call whatever method you want to invoke on that object.

In other words: you absolutely should not get into the business of doing such if/else chains. Every time your UI gets a new thing, or an element gets removed, you have to update code in a zillion of places.

Comment: can you show an example of this? I'm new to coding.

Comment: I probably shouldn't ask this as it might be opinioned based but would `Map<String, JComponet>` be more resource friendly than doing a `method(JComponent, String)`?

Comment: You are putting your efforts in the wrong place. Your first goal should be to design a clear, simple solution. Something that is easy to understand. And change. Because when run into real performance issues, then well, your code is designed to be changed and adapted easily! Seriously: you are  a newbie, trying things to get working. You totally, absolutely should not worry about "performance", or "resource friendliness", especially given that you don't understand what these terms actually *mean*. Rest assured: it is the overall design that drives performance, not using a map versus if/else.